# $scope.Apply undefined in v1.3

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am migrating my application to use angular js v1.2 to v1.3. My existing code having $scope.$apply like this

```
$scope.$apply(function () { })
```

Now as per new version change log this function is no longer available now. So what is the alternate approach or minimum code change I must do to incorporate my application with angular js version 1.3?

Comment: How do you find the function is no longer available? I am still using it with 1.3 and it can be found the source code too.

Comment: see in below link of migration guide. You can no longer invoke .bind, .call or .apply on a function in angular expressions. This is to disallow changing the behaviour of existing functions in an unforseen fashion.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is `$scope.$evalAsync(function(){})` if you have managed to somehow break the Angularjs codebase.
It would be good to see what version of angular you are including and how you have defined $scope.$apply()